# How to add .env file inside a NextJS folder into GitHub Actions

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, github-actions

[image]

I want to add `.env` file into GitHub Actions, but that file inside client folder. If I create from Github settings, it will only apply for outside folder, not within the client folder, is it right?

Comment: The point of `.env` files is to simulate, for local development, what's actually happening in production. If you want to set env vars in GitHub Actions, see e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv. Beyond that it's not at all clear what you're asking.